# Cross-origin requests AJAX requests to AWS S3 sometimes result in CORS error

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I need to get retrieve some publicly accessible files from S3.

That's my S3 CORS configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And here's my JS code:

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
    mode: 'cors',
});

const blob = await response.blob();
```

It works, but not always. Sometimes I have the following error in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-bycketuel/file.jpg' from origin 'https://my.host' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But after I reload the page (sometimes several times, sometimes just once) then the error is gone and I'm able to read the response object.

Comment: You need to whitelist {https://my-bycketuel / *} on {https://my.host/}. And that way issue would be resolved for you forever. It is cross platform access issue. Should be easy.

Comment: Another recommended way is you can use reverse proxy to resolve issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OP here.

I was looking at successful and unsuccessful requests in Chrome dev tools. I found that unsuccessful requests have Status code of: `200 OK (from disk cache)` when successful requests have Status code of: `200 OK`

When I disable caching using `cache: 'no-cache'` then the problem is gone.

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
        Origin: window.location.origin,
    },
});
```

I still don't understand why would cached request suffer from CORS issues, but at least I found a solution - or rather a workaround.

---

// EDIT:

I found I'm not alone: [Cached non CORS response conflicts with new CORS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498704/cached-non-cors-response-conflicts-with-new-cors-request)

Comment: This is a bug in S3's CORS implementation.  S3 fails to set `Vary: Origin` on responses to non-CORS requests, even when the bucket has CORS enabled... so Chrome assumes it can reuse the cached response in a CORS context, only to discover too late that it isn't going to work, because the cached response lacks `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ... https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161

Comment: Life saver. I looked all over the internets for many hours to find this bit of wisdom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing the

```
<AllowedMethod>Head</AllowedMethod>
```

on your config file.

I expect that is the reason you are having issues.

Make sure on Allowed Http Methods you chose Get,Head,Options as well include the Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Origin on your white list

Try that!

Good Luck

Comment: I've added the `<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>`, but the problem is not gone. 

But that's most weird to me is the fact that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and I can't find any reason or rule behind it.

Comment: Have you checked your white list ?

Comment: What whitelist do you mean?

I already found what causes an issue. It's somehow related to caching:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158189/cross-origin-requests-ajax-requests-to-aws-s3-sometimes-result-in-cors-error#answer-55163299